# 502 Bad Gateway The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

**when i am trying to submit this function save()  this shows   "502 Bad Gateway The server returned an invalid or incomplete response. "we didn't do any changes recently in this existing working code. is this a code error or miss configuration of server?  why i geting this error.?**

```
function save()
{


    $data = array('client_email' => $this->input->post('client_email'),'client_fname' => $this->input->post('client_fname'),'client_sname' => $this->input->post('client_sname'),'client_company' => $this->input->post('client_company'),'client_phone' => $this->input->post('client_phone')
);


 $our_current_client = $this->input->post('currenct_client');
  $this->order2model->form_update($data,$this->input->post('currenct_client'));

    $other_services_var = '';
    $count_otherss = 0;

    if($this->input->post('otherservices')!='')
    {
        $otherservices = $this->input->post('otherservices');
        $other_id = explode('_',$otherservices);

        $other_services_var = $other_id[1];

        $this->session->set_userdata('service', $other_id[1]);
    }




    if($other_services_var != '')
    {
        //$this->session->set_userdata('service', 'others_radio');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('service', $this->input->post('rb'));

        $this->session->unset_userdata('cull');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('cull_max');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('cull_min');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('cull_images');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('lr_image_sub');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('lr_image_del');

            $this->session->unset_userdata('strength');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('strength_images');
    }

    $rb = $this->input->post('rb');
    if($rb=='wed_custom')
    {

        $cull =  $this->input->post('cull_onoffswitch');
        $strength = $this->input->post('str_onoffswitch');
        $this->session->set_userdata('total_images_lr', $this->input->post('total_images_lr'));
        $this->session->set_userdata('lr_image_sub', $this->input->post('lr_image_sub'));
        $this->session->set_userdata('lr_image_del', $this->input->post('lr_image_del'));

        if($cull=='on')
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('cull', $this->input->post('cull_onoffswitch'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('cull_max', $this->input->post('cull_max'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('cull_min', $this->input->post('cull_min'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('cull_images', $this->input->post('cull_images'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('lr_image_sub', $this->input->post('lr_image_sub'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('lr_image_del', $this->input->post('lr_image_del'));
        }else{
            $this->session->unset_userdata('cull');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('cull_max');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('cull_min');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('cull_images');

        }
        if($strength=='on')
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('strength', $this->input->post('str_onoffswitch'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('strength_images', $this->input->post('strength_images'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('total_images_lr', $this->input->post('total_images_lr'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('lr_image_sub', $this->input->post('lr_image_sub'));
            $this->session->set_userdata('lr_image_del', $this->input->post('lr_image_del'));

        }else
        {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('strength');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('strength_images');

        }

    }

    $this->session->set_userdata('client_fname', $this->input->post('client_fname'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('client_sname', $this->input->post('client_sname'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('client_company', $this->input->post('client_company'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('client_phone', $this->input->post('client_phone'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('client_email', $this->input->post('client_email'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('rush', $this->input->post('onoffswitch'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('no_images', $this->input->post('no_images'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('file_format', $this->input->post('file_format'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('notes', $this->input->post('notes'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('active_tab', $this->input->post('active_tab'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('current_checked', $this->input->post('current_checked'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('our_client', $our_current_client);
    $this->session->set_userdata('item_details', $this->input->post('item_details'));
redirect('order3');

}
```

Comment: also write what your code is trying to do so that people will focus on particular area of code to debug faster

Comment: what server are you using ?

Comment: is it bug or server issue.?

Comment: using Linux server

Comment: yesterday its working fine.but suddenly stopped working without any modification

Comment: It seems set session was being called too much was caused the 502 error

Comment: #msvairam  tnx its working. more number of session are the problems

Comment: I am also facing same issue with the laravel site, is there any solution for it?